# SQL query to get a list of email ID's based on unit ID in comma-separated form

Tags: sql

I have a table `Emaildistributionlist` with 3 columns: `UnitID` which is unique, `Email` and `dept Name`. Here I write a query to get the list based on `id`,

```
SELECT distinct id, EMAIL 
FROM tblEmaildistributionlist  
WHERE dept like '%Contracts Dept%'
```

So I get an output like:

```
 ID=1  Email="cc@gmail.com" etc...
```

but the thing is one id has many email's so I want a output like

```
ID=1 Email=cc@gmail.com,rr@gmail.com,yy@gmail.com.`
```

All `emailid`'s in comma-separated form, in Email column.

What modification do I need in my query to get this result?

Comment: That entirely depends on what DBMS you are using and you haven't told us that.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for Mysql

```
SELECT 
     id, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(distinct EMAIL SEPARATOR ',') as Email 
from 
     tblEmaildistributionlist 
WHERE 
     dept like '%Contracts Dept%' 
GROUP BY 
     id
```

This for SQL Server

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+b.Email From tblEmaildistributionlist b WHERE b.id=a.id AND b.dept like '%Contracts Dept%' FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') as Email
FROM 
    tblEmaildistributionlist a
WHERE 
    a.dept like '%Contracts Dept%' 
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

And this is for Oracle 11g

```
SELECT 
     id, 
     LISTAGG(EMAIL, ',') as Email 
from 
     tblEmaildistributionlist 
WHERE 
     dept like '%Contracts Dept%' 
GROUP BY 
     id
```

Comment: Here am using sql server when i apply your query,it gives me an error like " Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression".How to solve..this..?

Comment: It may because I forgot to put `b` on `Email` to distinct `Email` from table `a` and `b`. So, it the subquery, it suppose to be `b.Email`

Comment: where you have given in sub query as b.email not distinct email,where i want to add b.email..please edit in the above query and clarify..

Comment: Still the same error, "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression". any other way is there like colleasce or some thing like that

Comment: There are total 4 id's are there and each id has many email are there as i mentioned early nw it is showing ID=1 email: aa@ gmail.com,ID=1 email=cc@gmail.com but after query i want distinct ID ie ID=1,email:aa@gmail.com,dd@gmail.com.whatever email in that corresponding ID wants to be in comma seperated form under there respective coloumn.

Comment: I Have Tried this " select distinct id , COALESCE(EMAIL + ', ', + '') as EMAIL from tblEmaildistributionlist WHERE dept like '%Contracts Dept%' " but it is not given the exact output it displays like this ID =1 email=cc@gmail.com, only the comma coming after email not the second email is coming , what i want to change to get the output ,am ok with any of these solution

Comment: I solved it by adding FOR XML PATH ('') at the end  Now the query will be SELECT
    a.id,
 STUFF((SELECT ','+b.Email From tblEmaildistributionlist b WHERE b.id=a.id AND b.dept like '%Contracts Dept%'FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') as Email
FROM 
    tblEmaildistributionlist a
WHERE 
    a.dept like '%Contracts Dept%' 
GROUP BY
    a.id

Comment: Wow...  You figure it out. Nice share. You are welcome. Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.
its working fine

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + EmailId 
FROM StudentDetails 
SELECT @listStr

give out like this - email@doamin.com,emaol1@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

```
    select  a.ID,Stuff((select distinct  ','+ b.EMAIL from tblEmaildistributionlist b 
   where b.ID=a.ID and b.dept like '%Contracts Dept%' FOR XML PATH ('')  ),1,1,'') AS EMAIL
     from  tblEmaildistributionlist a
    WHERE 
     a.dept like '%Contracts Dept%'
     group by a.ID
```

Perfectly Working....